# Trying to use jdbc driver for postgresql but it's not working

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, osx-snow-leopard

I have added the jdbc driver to my classpath as far as I know i.e. I added the following to my .profile

export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:location/to/the/jarfile.jar

When I compile my java program I always get this error

```
javac v9.java
v9.java:8: <identifier> expected
 Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");//load the driver
          ^
v9.java:8: illegal start of type
 Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");//load the driver
           ^
2 errors
```

This is driving me insane, any help would be awesome. I'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard

The java program is here

```
import java.sql.*;

public class v9
{
 String dbURL = "jdbc:postgresql:mydb";
 String user = "UserName";
 String password = "pswd";
 C  try
{
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");//load the driver
// Connect to the database
Connection DBconn = DriverManager.getConnection( dbURL, user, password );
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Error has nothing to do with jdbc & progress, but wrong typed java code. Big letter "C" before "try"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - you need a method somewhere:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class V9
{
    public static final String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    public static final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/party";
    public static final String username = "pgsuper";
    public static final String password = "pgsuper";

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            System.out.println(conn.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your comments are correct, they aren't consistent with the username and password you're passing.  Your comment says user is "postgres", but the string says "UserName".  You didn't post the errors, so I can only guess.

Comment: Sorry, the comment is irrelevant. I didn't want to post the login information to my computer but I know they are correct.

Comment: I fixed the code.  This works.  Change the url, username, and password for your situation.

Comment: Your newest edit works :D hurray! You saved my evening, thank you so much!